# getting wrong output in java String, and == sign

Tags: java

What i have,

suppose I am creating two object like below,

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = s1;

System.out.println("== comparison "+ s1==s2);
```

i am expecting the output is

> == comparison true

but i get

> false

What is the problem?

I am not getting output as my expectation.

Question
why it is not matching the expected output.

please reply and explain why it is coming like this.

Thanks in advance
tofek khan

Comment: Do `System.out.println("== comparison "+ (s1==s2));`. You're concatening s1 with `"== comparison "`.

Comment: this is a basic comprehension in java, try to understand difference between `.equal()` and `==`

Comment: It's not a dupe (of that one anyway)

Comment: Guys pay attention to the question! He assigns s2 = s1.

Answer (score 10):

It is because of [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

The `+` operator has a higher precedence than `==`.

Thus you compare the concatenation of `"== comparison " + s1` with `s2`. Since strings are immutable a new string instance is created that contains `"== comparison abc"` and this instance can never be the same as `s2`, because `s2` still references `"abc"`.

Use this instead

```
"== comparison " + (s1 == s2)
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: In case of doubt add some extra parentheses :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
System.out.println("== comparison "+ s1==s2);
```

is actually doing

```
System.out.println(("== comparison "+ s1)==s2);
```

try

```
System.out.println("== comparison "+ (s1==s2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it prints ("== comparison " + s1) == s2, which is obviously false

This is what you actually need

```
System.out.println("== comparison " + (s1 == s2));
```

Comment: Thanks all of you, for giving good answar that is benificial for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("== comparison "+ s1==s2);
```

This should be changed to

```
System.out.println("== comparison "+ (s1==s2));
```

in order to prepare the comparison result in advance of text output. Also get used to comparing Strings with `.equals()` method, because you probably want to compare the values, not check for reference equality. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)